# Yammer search V2 API

Tags: yammer

I.m trying to use Yammer V2 search endpoint but couldn't find any article that can help with CORS error. When I try V2 search, it just keeps giving CORS error however I'm able to use V1 search without any issue - so can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here ?

V1 search -

```
yam.platform.request(
 {
 url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json"
 , method: "GET"
 , data: { 'search': 'test'}
 , success: function (msg) {
 console.log('success');
 }
 , error: function (msg) { console.log("Error..." + msg); }
 }
 )            
 }
});
```

V2 Search -

```
yam.platform.request(
{
 url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v2/search/models"
, method: "GET"
, data: { 'search':'test', 'start':0, 'size':20, 'model_types':'threads', 
'_network':5225275392, 'relevance':'DEFAULT'}
 , success: function (msg) {
 Display(msg);
}
  , error: function (msg) { console.log("Error..." + msg); }
}
)            
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, this API is unsupported for use by external developers. The APIs under the V2 endpoint are primarily for first-party application use only. Support for searching is limited to the [V1 endpoint](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/searchjson). The [supported APIs](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits) are listed in the main documentation.